# конфигурирование DI в Laravel или Yii2

Tags: yii2, laravel, di, контейнеры

Кто как конфигурирует DI контейнер в этих фреймворках? В документации к обоим сказано следующее: вызываем метод контейнера что то типо bind (как в ларавеле), или set (как в yii2) и передаём этим методам название зависимости и callback. И что, если мне нужно настроить 10-20 классов с разными скалярными значениями, которые нужно вытащить предварительно из базы или из конфига, мне все эти callback'и в одном файле хранить?
Нельзя в них сделать что-то типо, как в zf? Чтобы был конфиг, а в нём массив с сервисами и фабриками этих сервисов.